# How can I get all registered URL schemas on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

We can start an app with a URL schema such as:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]];
 //will start mail application
```

But how can I find out all the registered application URL schema on my iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get it. There's no API for that.

You can try browsing through [`these`](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme) for the ones you need.

Comment: thank u very much, at last i found this class UIDocumentInteractionController to finish my job.

Answer (score 1):

No there are no api or function for this. but you can check a list here - http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes